# How to disable a json response dates array angularjs datepicker example

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

i would like to create a popupDatePicker starting from an array of dates(retrieved from a json response) but looking for it on internet i don't find any simple example that respect my question. In my code it doesn't work...

**This is my example.js:**

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myDisabledDates =  ['2017-09-22T09:13:00.000Z','2017-09-23T09:13:00.000Z']
  $scope.options = {
    dateDisabled: disabled,
    startingDay: 1
  };
  $scope.formats = ['yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
  $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];  
 /*  $scope.open1 = function() {
    $scope.popup1.opened = true;
  };
  $scope.popup1 = {
    opened: false
  };*/
  function disabled(data) {
    var date = data.date.toISOString().slice(0, 10), 
      mode = data.mode;

    return mode === 'day' && $scope.myDisabledDates.indexOf(date) > -1;
  }
});
```

And index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
    <pre>Selected date is: <em>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em></pre>

    <div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
      <div uib-datepicker ng-model="dt"  class="well well-sm" datepicker-options="options"></div>  
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error from your code and if so can you add it to the question.

Comment: This is my code: https://plnkr.co/edit/akayxvE14DsFdOLbQV5T?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your current code is that you are evaluating a 10 character string against a 24 character string.  To fix this, change the return from disabled() to be:

```
return mode === 'day' && $scope.myDisabledDates.some(x => x.slice(0, 10) === date);
```

Or in browsers that don't support arrow functions (IE):

```
return mode === 'day' && $scope.myDisabledDates.some(function(x) {
  return x.slice(0, 10) === date;
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work... https://plnkr.co/edit/akayxvE14DsFdOLbQV5T?p=preview

Comment: @SteVizzo - what isn't working?  9/22 & 9/23 are disabled.  Are you sure you're looking at September and not October?

Comment: I found the mistake...i think you are using chrome because with ie11 it doesn't work....doesn0t appear the calendar

Comment: @SteVizzo - are you saying that the calendar doesn't appear at all?  are you getting errors in the console?

Comment: yes i found errors but i don't understand why: SCRIPT1002: Errore di sintassi
example.js (21,61)
SCRIPT5022: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap.demo due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap.demo' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/nomod?p0=ui.bootstrap.demo
   at Anonymous function (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js:2183:11)

Comment: @SteVizzo - you're getting that error when you run from the plunker?

Comment: @SteVizzo - the issue is that IE does not support arrow functions.  I modified my answer to cover this issue

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much!!! Just a thing, how can i use the datePicker-popup element with this plnkr?

Comment: @SteVizzo - that's separate question that should handled under a new post.  Please close out this issue by marking my answer as Accepted and then post any additional questions under a new post.